# Should I overstep my boss?

Tags: professionalism, ethics, manager, project-management

Let me give some background first:
I'm a junior front-end developer, working in the company for like 8 months and I have a degree in IT Management.
I just talked about my degree because it matters to the question.
Even though I work with the developers, I belong to another sector (Marketing).
So, I answer to the marketing manager.

That said, my company is going trought some changes. We are starting to use agile. Since I have a good knowledge at this area, I was talking to the Project Manager of the company (outsourced) giving some tips to where it could improve, at least in my sector. He agreed with my tips and said that those tips that I have mentioned was suggested to my boss, but "he lacks initiative" and told me that I could be the one to go forward implementing SCRUM in my sector.
For that, I would need to go to his boss, and get the permission to do so.

My question is: Doing that, I feel like I would be acting behind my manager's back, and in doing so, I wonder if I would be bitting off more than I can chew, since I'm just a junior dev.

**What is the worst scenario for me doing that? And ultimately, should I?**

I really really dont want to create an "bad vibe" with my boss.

**UPDATE:**

My PM approached me today and told me to be the SCRUM Master on my sector, because I was the more qualified to the position. For this, he stated that I should leave a little of the developer work and focus more in leading, being a SM.

That is a major advance for me, but I stated to him that I would not like to act behind my manager's back, which he told that "it wasn't like this". So, he told that he would be talking with my manager's boss about this and that we should make this happen, saying that he could go to our sector's next weekly meet.

Is there something that I should do in here? Or just "accept my fate"?

Answer (score 4):

Do NOT attempt to overstep your manager unless there is a very, very good reason for it.  It's professional suicide and will likely end up in either a highly unfavourable performance evaluation or worse.  If you can't convince your manager to consider it properly, then you haven't pitched your proposal well enough to them.

A better option would be to speak to the Project Manager about how you can pitch this better to your manager rather than try to go around them.  If the Project Manager also isn't able to quantify the benefits sufficiently to convince your manager then I would question the wisdom of heeding their advice with this.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario you change something behind you manager's back, and he doesn't know what's going on suddenly. Makes him look bad, makes you look bad.

Draft your methods going forward and present your plan to your manager, and ask that you take charge under his supervision. This is an opportunity as a junior to take on a project you're interested in. *But*, your manager may also have valuable input, mentoring or advisory to complement whatever it is you draft.

Granted, it doesn't guarantee you'll lead those changes. I think it goes without saying, however, that in most cases you shouldn't subvert your manager.